# how to get the least number of elements whose sum is greater than n?

Tags: python

```
a = ['a', 'bc', 'def', 'hijk']
n = 5
i = 0
l = 0
for x in a:
  l += len(x)
  if l > n:
    break
  i += 1

print(i) # get 2 meaning the 3rd element.
```

I use the above code to get the least number of elements whose total length is greater than n. It involves for-loop. I am not sure if for-loop is efficient. Is there any more efficient implementation than this?

Comment: Is the order of the list important? If not, start from the largest element first.

Comment: The order is important.

Comment: Could maybe be micro-optimized a little, but... why? Is it not fast enough for you?

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes a `for` loop is appropriate here

You do, indeed, only want to process elements until you reach the total, and no more. Your list might have millions of items, but only need a few dozen to reach the desired total. Any method that computes the length of *every* string, without knowing if the later strings are needed, will perform poorly in such a situation.

Therefore it makes sense to use a method, like `for`, that will terminate early.

The other methods available to Python, such as list comprehension and `numpy` vectorized methods, would involve processing all the strings even if that was not necessary.